# Convert function into observable

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, google-cloud-firestore, angularfire2

Can anybody help make this function an observable? I need to use it to check if a document already exists based on query. I need to subscribe to it so that I can create a document if not.

Currently it gives me an error:

> A function whose declared type is neither 'void' nor 'any' must return
>   a value.

```
    exists(query: Vehicle): Observable<boolean>{
        this.afs.collection('vehicles',
            ref => 
            ref
            //queries
            .where("country","==", query.country)
          ).snapshotChanges().subscribe(
            res => {       

              if (res.length > 0){
                //the document exists
                return true
              }
              else {
                return false
              }
          }); 
    }//end exists()
```

Then I wan to call it

```
this.vehicleService.exists({country:"USA})
  .subscribe(x => {
    if (x) {
      //create a new doc
    }
});
```

Comment: What version of `rxjs` are you using?

Comment: I'm using rxjs v6.2.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of subscribe, you should `pipe` the result through `map`, as you want to transform the result into a boolean.

Secondly, the compiler is complaining because you've provided a return type, but don't actually return anything, so make sure you return the `Observable`.

It should look something like this:

```
  exists(query: Vehicle): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.afs.collection('vehicles',
      ref =>
        //queries
        ref.where("country", "==", query.country)
    ).snapshotChanges().pipe(
      // Use map to transform the emitted value into true / false
      map(res => res && res.length > 0)
    )
  }//end exists()
```

Comment: Yes, that did it.  If you want, edit your answer with this code so that you can take credit:

  exists(query: Vehicle): Observable<boolean>{
    return this.afs.collection('vehicles',
        ref => 
        ref
        //queries
        .where("country","==", query.country)
      ).snapshotChanges().pipe(
        map(
          res => {
            if (res.length > 0){
              //the document exists
              return true
            }
            else {
              return false
            }
          })//map 
        )//pipe
  }//end exists()

Comment: @jorluiseptor How come you're doing if/else instead of just `res && res.length > 0`?

Comment: Ignore my previous comment. Your code is more concise and does the same. Thanks for your help!